# Export to PDF/Jpg functionality unable to export the entire timeine chart as pdf/jpg. Data get chopped off

Tags: timeline, anychart

Using Export to PDF/Jpg functionality, we are unable to export the entire timeine chart as pdf/jpg. We have found the below document, however that just exports the screen image that is visible to the user. So, some chart data gets chopped-off. Can you please help
**Code used for pdf export:** chart.saveAsPdf();
**Code used for jpg export:**
chart.saveAsJpg({
"quality": 0.3,
"forceTransparentWhite": false,
"filename": "My Chart JPG"
});

**Code used for pdf export:** chart.saveAsPdf();
**Code used for jpg export:**
chart.saveAsJpg({
"quality": 0.3,
"forceTransparentWhite": false,
"filename": "My Chart JPG"
});

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.